# The application has no keychain access groups enabled

Tags: ios, xamarin.forms, xamarin.ios, azure-ad-msal

We have a Xamarin.Forms application, and trying to use MSAL authentication, and face an issue with iOS project. It works in an emulator, but when built by the Azure pipeline and installed on real iPhone, an exception happens:

> MSAL.Xamarin.iOS.4.14.0.MsalClient Exception: ErrorCode:
> missing_entitlements Microsoft.Identity.Client.MsalClientException:
> The application does not have keychain access groups enabled in the
> Entitlements.plist. As a result, there was a failure to save to the
> iOS keychain. The keychain access group
> "OURID.com.microsoft.adalcache' is not enabled in the
> Entitlements.plist...

OURID is of course a replacement for the real value.

Here is what we have in the entitlements.plist:

```
 <key>keychain-access-groups</key>
  <array>
     <string>$(AppIdentifierPrefix)com.microsoft.adalcache</string>
  </array>
```

In B2CAuthenticationService constructor:

```
            var builder = PublicClientApplicationBuilder.Create(B2CConstants.ClientID)
            .WithB2CAuthority(B2CConstants.AuthoritySignInSignUp)
            .WithIosKeychainSecurityGroup(B2CConstants.IOSKeyChainGroup)
            .WithRedirectUri($"msal{B2CConstants.ClientID}://auth");
```

What can I be missing that causes the exception?

ADDED: If I add a variable replacement task to the pipeline, even then those can only replace values in xml and json config files; not plist files.

Comment: You are testing in real device or simulator?

Comment: @Ali Ahmad Both. On simulator no issues, the exception happens only on the real iphone.

Comment: So you are using a provisioning profile to build application on Iphone?

Comment: @Ali Ahmad Yes, in Azure pipeline

Comment: Your issue is when you are deploying application goto info.plist and in manual provisioning select your entitlements in Custom Entitlements field.

Comment: @Ali Ahmad I don't see there such a field. Should I open it as a text?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/216590/discussion-between-ali-ahmad-and-david-shochet).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I fixed the issue by editing the project in a text editor and specifying entitlements.plist in

```
    <CodesignEntitlements>Entitlements.plist</CodesignEntitlements>
```

within property group

```
  <PropertyGroup Condition=" '$(Configuration)|$(Platform)' == 'Debug|iPhone' ">
```

When I did it previously through the project GUI, it affected only property group

```
<PropertyGroup Condition=" '$(Configuration)|$(Platform)' == 'Debug|iPhoneSimulator' ">
```

That is why it worked for me in the emulator, but not on the real device.